# Android Plugin for gradle

Tags: android, plugins, gradle

Is anyone know how to retrieve a buildConfigField in a plugin gradle task ?

Code from the  task plugin

```
@TaskAction
def renameApk() {

    if (project.android != null ) {
        project.android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            if (variant.name == "release") {
            // get the variant buildConfigField ENV_CODE
           }

    }
```

Code from the gradle of My Test Application :

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "ENV_CODE", '"WSTEST"'
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible, your best solution is probably to define the APK names somewhere else. Where you match the variant name and get the apk name.